# Custom self-made module doesn't show content after J3.4.3 upgrade

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-module

I've create a module which uses the standard contact component to show content but it will not work anymore after upgrade from j3.4.1 to 3.4.3. Maybe there is someone from the coding team who could have a look at the attached zipped module and explain how to fix the issue..

The following errors are shown once I set error reporting to maximum:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method modVorstandHelper::getList() should not be called statically in .. /modules/mod_vorstand/mod_vorstand.php on line 21
Notice: Array to string conversion in .. /administrator/components/com_contact/models/contacts.php on line 134
```

and for each entry in auto generated table:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ... /modules/mod_vorstand/tmpl/default.php on line 29  
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ... /modules/mod_vorstand/tmpl/default.php on line 30
```

which is probably a result of the above mentioned site problems.
In J3.4.1 all is working fine but with the same 2 site problems above.

J3.4.1 is running here: http://www.trudeo.de/st.antonius/vorstand

J3.4.3 is running here: http://www.trudeo.de/st.antonius1/vorstand

There is no possibility to add the module in this forum but can be downloaded here www.trudeo.de/mod_vorstand.zip

Thanks

Comment: You should share your code here. At least the relevant parts of mod_vorstand.php and the template (tmpl/default.php)

Comment: Strict errors and notices are not a massive issue and can be turned off. There are loads of answers on Google for this. I'm afraid unless you share your code on here, people are very unlikely to help

Comment: Hi fruppel and Lodder, the complete code can be downloaded here www.trudeo.de/mod_vorstand.zip . You can compare the vorstand module on both joomla versions (links in initial posting). The strict errors and notices on both versions but obviousely the J-Versions doesn't handle the module on the same way. 3.4.3 is a clone of 3.4.1 made with akeeba and just Joomla updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to get items from the contacts model but the result is probably empty.

## Notices

*helper.php line 54*

```
// Category filter
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', array()));
```

try to change that line to this:

```
// Category filter
$model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', ''));
```

The problem is the default value of your catid parameter. If you do not set the catid in the module options, it will default to an empty array. The contacts model will not find anything if you filter with an **empty** category ID array.

---

## Strict error

Change

```
function getList($params)
```

in *helper.php line 25* to

```
public static function getList($params)
```

to get rid of the strict error

Comment: @LupoNRW - Also note that there has been a [Pull Request on Github](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/7619) for something like this. It might be worth applying the patch and testing too

Comment: Thanks fruppel so far for fast support. About the proposed changes in helper.php line 54: the module is configured via backend to use only category called vorstand. Removing the array doesn't help here. The Strict error is gone now after i've added the public static to the function.

Comment: Removed the category filter line 54 now completely and the notices (Array to string conversion) are gone but the difference is still there. 3.4.1 shows content, 3.4.3 not with error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...

Comment: Can you try to remove  everything between line 31 and 64 in your helper.php? So that you just have $model = JModelLegacy... and $items = ...? Try that and see if you get any results. And if you get results then add the removed lines one by one to see which one causes the problem.

Comment: Now the module uses the complete contact list without selection of the category and shows the names but not the pictures and the function they have in our organisation. Result is shown on the J3.4.3 link.

Comment: that's good. now you see that the problem is in one of the filters you apply after line 31. you only get the names and not the images and positions because you removed line 43 where you select additional fields. add one line from the removed lines back check if everything works and then add the next line until you find your problem

Comment: It seems the issue is caused by the list.select condition which initiate the DB lookup

Comment: are you sure? try $model->setState('list.select', 'a.*'); to select all columns from database. Another thing i spotted is the missing 'a.' before ordering in line 60

Comment: ha... strange. in the $model->setState('list.select', ... definition i found one space between  a.telephone and the trailing ' . which represents the code wordwrap. I've removed them and it works except the category selection doesn't work because i've removed the filter statement in order to fix the array issue. if i put them back, category selection works but array issue is there again.

Comment: so question is how it should look correctly if i want to select only category id 17. Now i have: $model->setState('filter.category_id', $params->get('catid', '17')); and this is obviousely wrong.

Comment: hm... that should not be wrong. did you set a catid in your model options? 17 is only the default value which will be taken if 'catid' is empty. can you check the result of var_dump($params->get('catid', '17')); ?

Comment: catid 17 = vorstand , the right category i want to be shown here. array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "17"
} will be shown when i try var_dump. normally the module is configured in the backend which category should be used and should be assigned to the module

Comment: to see what's going on you can go to file /administrator/components/com_contact/models/contacts.php and insert $query->dump(); die; before the return $query at the end of the file. can you post the result pls? maybe we can find out what changed between 3.4.1 and 3.4.3 because at the moment I don't see anything which would cause this

Comment: OK set back to array() in the category filter and it works except the notices which could be hiden by dissabling the error reporting. No clean solution but ... finally the terrible space in the list.select clausel was "mis"-interpreted in J3.4.3 :) thanks a lot for your immediate support fruppel and also Lodder for the hint with the Github i was not aware of.

Comment: fruppel: i've added the $query->dump(); die; and get white screen once refreshed with the same statement: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/trudeo.de/st.antonius1/administrator/components/com_contact/models/contacts.php on line 134

Comment: okay hard to tell without further investigations. if it works for you it should be okay now :)

Answer (score 0):

Working on a similar problem, I found that previously successful `$param->get()` requests are working 3.4.0 code must be changed to `$this->param->get()` to work in 3.4.3+.

Also, a couple of properties - `access-view` and `access-edit` - appear to no longer be used. I found Krumo to be handy for tracking this down.